# Update datatime with string 'Hour:Minute:Second.Micronsecond'

Tags: ruby

How to update the `old_datetime` with `"09:00:09.0012"`

old_datetime = `Fri, 07 Feb 2014 00:00:00 +0000` (datetime type)

So that new_datetime == `Fri, 07 Feb 2014 09:00:09.0012 +0000`

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate in error; The linked question is very close, and the basic idea can be used, but it's not an exact duplicate.  I flagged it for a moderator to reopen it. SBT.

Comment: @theTinMan Took care of that for ya

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'
new_datetime = DateTime.parse(old_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT') + "09:00:09.0012")
```